# Get discount data from adjustment object

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce2

Is it possible to get, from one of the `cart.adjustments` of type `discount`, whether the discount was added with a coupon code, and if so, what that coupon code is?

Comment: Is this for Commerce 1 or 2? You tagged both on the question.

Comment: @BradBell It's for Commerce 2, sorry about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An adjustment will take a snapshot of the source object that contained the rule for its application.

So the following is an array of a discounts attribute if you have a discount adjustment

```
{{ adjustment.sourceSnapshot }}
```

You could get the coupon code with

```
{{ adjustment.sourceSnapshot.code }}
```